# Server Error System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, iis-7

The entire error message:

> Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

Everywhere the solution for this problem is the re-registering aspNet by using aspnet_regiis.exe. But it did not work for me.

I have also tried the 1st and 2nd solutions [proposed by the microsoft support team](https://blogs.iis.net/webtopics/system-typeloadexception-for-system-servicemodel-activation-httpmodule-in-asp-net-4) but still the same problem.

i'm trying to host my WCF Service on Windows server 2008, IIS7 using .NET 4

i have run out of ideas.

Comment: post the entire error message along with stack trace if any

Comment: @Rahul i added the rest of the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to IIS manager, in the left pane expand the node with the computer's name, then expand the Web Sites node, and then select the Default Web Site,double click Handler mappings in the Features View.
In the list of application mappings, verify that the .svc file is mapped to the aspnet_isapi.dll. If the file has not been mapped:
1- Click Add Managed Handler.

2- Type *.svc into the Request path.

3- Type System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandlerFactory, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 into the Type textbox.

4- Type svc-Integrated-4.0 into the Name: textbox.
Click OK.

5- Click Add Script Map.

6- Type *.svc into the Request path.

7- Type %SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll into the Executable: text box.

8- Type svc-ISAPI-2.0 into the Name: text box.
Click OK.

9- - Go to modules and delete ServiceModel.

Answer (score 0):

See MSDN documentation on [Troubleshooting: Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel...'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh169179(v=nav.90).aspx)

You need to run the below command from command prompt as **Administrator**

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -iru
```

Then perform an

```
iisreset
```

Comment: yes i have already read that page, and did all the steps, but still have the same problem, does it have a relation with the ServiceModel? i had a look on IIS modules, and there are two ServiceModels, 1st ServiceModel 2nd ServiceModel-4.0